# Locate MacOS X Framework folder without using FSFindFolder

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager, macos-carbon

I have an old piece of code that uses **FSFindFolder** to get the location of MacOS X Framework folder using folderType **kFrameworksFolderType**. FSFindFolder has been deprecated and therefore I need to update this.**NSFileManager's** **URLForDirectory** does not contain any equivalent **NSSearchPathDirectory** constant. Is there a way to locate the Framework folder apart from using FSFindFolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the frameworks directory has always been located in `/Library` and `~/Library` for as long as OS X has existed.

Since this is legacy code, use `NSLibraryDirectory` and append `"/Frameworks"` to the path and you should be fine.

Note that there are lots of other "standard" paths that don't, or no longer, have standard directory search constants: Preferences, LaunchAgents, and Services to mention just a few. I construct their paths based on `NSLibraryDirectory` and have never had an issue (and my software runs on systems with truly bizarre configurations).